# Apple Watch app: run an MKDirectionsRequest through the parent iOS app in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm writing an Apple Watch app and at some point I need to get an information about the walking or driving distance from the user's current location to a specific place.

As recommended by Apple in its [Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/DesigningaWatchKitApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH3-SW5), I'm delegating all the hard work to the iOS app, by calling `openParentApplication` from the Apple Watch and implementing the `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` function on the iOS app side. So, the iOS app is in charge of: 1) computing directions to the destination place using MapKit, and 2) returning the fetched distance and expected time to the Apple Watch.

This operation is made through MapKit's `MKDirectionsRequest`, which tends to be "slow" (like, 1 or 2 seconds). If I test my code directly in the iOS app with the same arguments, everything works well: I get the expected time and distance response. However, from inside the Apple Watch app, the callback (`reply` parameter of `openParentApplication`) is never called and the device never gets its information back.

**UPDATE 1:** Replaced by update 3.

**UPDATE 2:** Actually, there is no timeout as I suspected in the beginning, but it only seems to work if the iOS app runs in foreground on the iPhone. If I try to run the query from the Apple Watch app without touching anything on the iPhone Simulator (i.e.: the app is woken up in the background), then nothing happens. As soon as I tap my app's icon on the iPhone Simulator, putting it frontmost, the Apple Watch receives the reply.

**UPDATE 3:** As requested by Duncan, below is the full code involved, with emphasis on where execution path is lost:

(in class `WatchHelper`)

```
var callback: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)?

func handleWatchKitExtensionRequest(userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!) {
    // Create results and callback object for this request
    results = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
    callback = reply
    // Process request
    if let op = userInfo["op"] as String? {
        switch op {
        case AppHelper.getStationDistanceOp:
            if let uic = userInfo["uic"] as Int? {
                if let transitType = userInfo["transit_type"] as Int? {
                    let transportType: MKDirectionsTransportType = ((transitType == WTTripTransitType.Car.rawValue) ? .Automobile : .Walking)
                    if let loc = DatabaseHelper.getStationLocationFromUIC(uic) {
                        // The following API call is asynchronous, so results and reply contexts have to be saved to allow the callback to get called later
                        LocationHelper.sharedInstance.delegate = self
                        LocationHelper.sharedInstance.routeFromCurrentLocationToLocation(loc, withTransportType: transportType)
                    }
                }
            }
        case ... // Other switch cases here
        default:
            NSLog("Invalid operation specified: \(op)")
        }
    } else {
        NSLog("No operation specified")
    }
}

func didReceiveRouteToStation(distance: CLLocationDistance, expectedTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    // Route information has been been received, archive it and notify caller
    results!["results"] = ["distance": distance, "expectedTime": expectedTime]
    // Invoke the callback function with the received results
    callback!(results)
}
```

(in class `LocationHelper`)

```
func routeFromCurrentLocationToLocation(destination: CLLocation, withTransportType transportType: MKDirectionsTransportType) {
    // Calculate directions using MapKit
    let currentLocation = MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation()
    var request = MKDirectionsRequest()
    request.setSource(currentLocation)
    request.setDestination(MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: destination.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)))
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = false
    request.transportType = transportType
    let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
    directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler({ (response, error) -> Void in
        // This is the MapKit directions calculation completion handler
        // Problem is: execution never reaches this completion block when called from the Apple Watch app
        if response != nil {
            if response.routes.count > 0 {
                self.delegate?.didReceiveRouteToStation?(response.routes[0].distance, expectedTime: response.routes[0].expectedTravelTime)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

**UPDATE 4**: The iOS app is clearly setup to be able to receive location updates in the background, as seen in the screenshot below:

[image: Location services are "Always" enabled for my app]

So the question now becomes: is there any way to "force" an `MKDirectionsRequest` to happen in the background?

Comment: Hey @Romain, did you ever find a solution for this problem? I've been trying to figure it out myself.

Comment: @brynbodayle Nope, but if you do find something, please post an answer!

Comment: @brynbodayle We finally got something working! Check out the accepted solution and see if it also helps for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works in an app that I am working on. It also works with the app in the background so I think it's safe to say that `MKDirectionsRequest` will work in background mode. Also, this is called from the AppDelegate and is wrapped in a `beginBackgroundTaskWithName` tag.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                MKPlacemark *destPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(destLat, destLon) addressDictionary:nil];
                MKPlacemark *currentPlacemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currLat, currLon) addressDictionary:nil];

                NSMutableDictionary __block *routeDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                MKRoute __block *routeDetails=nil;

                MKDirectionsRequest *directionsRequest = [[MKDirectionsRequest alloc] init];
                [directionsRequest setSource:[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:currentPlacemark]];
                [directionsRequest setDestination:[[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:destPlacemark]];
                directionsRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportTypeAutomobile;

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){

                        MKDirections *directions = [[MKDirections alloc] initWithRequest:directionsRequest];

                        [directions calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler:^(MKDirectionsResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                            if (error) {
                                NSLog(@"Error %@", error.description);

                            } else {
                                NSLog(@"ROUTE: %@",response.routes.firstObject);
                                routeDetails = response.routes.firstObject;

                                [routeDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",routeDetails.distance] forKey:@"routeDistance"];
                                [routeDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",routeDetails.expectedTravelTime]  forKey:@"routeTravelTime"];

                                NSLog(@"Return Dictionary: %@",routeDict);

                                reply(routeDict);
                            }
                        }];

                    });
            });
```

**EDIT from OP**: The code above probably works in ObjC, but the exact reason why it works is that it is not using `MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation()`. So the working code for me looks as follows:

```
func routeFromCurrentLocationToLocation(destination: CLLocation, withTransportType transportType: MKDirectionsTransportType) {
    // Calculate directions using MapKit
    let currentLocation = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng), addressDictionary: nil))
    var request = MKDirectionsRequest()
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is crazy: I was going to reply on my own question, but you posted this answer meanwhile, and it corresponds to the answer I was going no to post. In fact, the solution lies in not using `MKMapItem.mapItemForCurrentLocation()`, but I'm not sure why. I will update your answer by clearly mentioning that, so that people who come here understand the problem, and then I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your completion handler has an `error` object you should check what's passed in.

`openParentApplication` and `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest` worked fine in Xcode 6.2 Beta 2 and seem to be broken as of Xcode 6.2 Beta 3 (6C101). I always get the error

```
Error Domain=com.apple.watchkit.errors Code=2 
"The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply() in -[UIApplicationDelegate ...]"
```

So we probably have to wait for the next beta.

Comment: Thanks, @zisoft. I've also seen this error countless times while developing for the Apple Watch. However, in that specific case, the completion handler is not even called, because execution halts before the `MKDirectionsRequest` completion handler itself. I'm surprised that the Watch app doesn't crash with the error you described, because technically, `reply` is also never called in that context... Might be an SDK bug but I'm not sure...

Comment: Some county does't provide route direction thats way you are getting this error, http://www.apple.com/ios/feature-availability/#maps-directions

Answer (score 0):

In the code extract that you gave us (which I presume was from `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest`, although you don't specifically indicate so), you do not call the reply block that was passed to your iPhone app in `openParentApplication`. That is the first thing that should be checked in these scenarios for other developers with this issue.

However, your second update indicates that it is working fine when the iPhone app is in the foreground. This almost certainly indicates that the issue is one of location services permissions. If your app has permission to access location services when it is running, but does not have "always" permissions, then your WatchKit Extension will not be able to receive results from MapKit when your iPhone app is not running. Requesting (and receiving) such a permission should resolve your issue.

For people more generally who have the problem of not seeing the reply block being called, in Swift that method is defined,

```
optional func application(_ application: UIApplication!, 
handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, 
reply reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!)
```

Reply thus provides you with a block, to which you execute while passing it AnyObject.  You must return something, even if it is `reply(nil)`, or you will get the error message, "The UIApplicationDelegate in the iPhone App never called reply()..."

In Objective-C, the method is defined,

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply
```

Note that here, `replyInfo` must be an NSDictionary that is serializable to a property list file. The contents of this dictionary are still at your discretion and you may specify nil.

Interestingly therefore, this might be a good example of an API where there is a clear advantage in using Swift over Objective-C, as in Swift you can apparently simply pass any object, without the need to serialise many objects to NSData chunks in order to be able to pass them via the NSDictionary in Objective-C.

Comment: Hi @duncan-babbage, thanks for trying to help. I've updated my question following your comment. The `reply` block is indeed never called but as I tried to clarify, it is because execution does not reach its call anyway. Your suggestion regarding location services is also useful but I've already been careful at asking to get location updates "always" for my app, so this shouldn't be the problem either. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, in my case, it turns out that the dictionary being returned needs to have data that can be serialized. If you are trying to return `CLLocation` data, you will need to use `NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver` to serialize it or convert it into an `NSString` before passing it to the `reply()`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @rmp. I also faced this issue but managed to sort it out. The problem I'm having now really lies in how iOS handles the directions request. It seems to not fire it until the app is in foreground...

Comment: @Romain have you tried wrapping process request in `beginBackgroundTaskWithName`  to give the phone more time to run? It helped with the app I am working on.

Comment: I remember I tried doing this with no success... But I still think it might be path to follow, maybe I did it wrong. Do you have some sample code to share, just to see if it solves my issue? Thanks!

Comment: Here is a snippit of what we are doing:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Romain, your code saved my day. I just converted to Swift

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), { () -> Void in


            let destPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinateDestinazione, addressDictionary: nil)

            let miaLocation = self.Manager.location.coordinate
            let currentPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: miaLocation, addressDictionary: nil)



            var routeDetails = MKRoute()
            let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
            directionRequest.setSource(MKMapItem(placemark: currentPlacemark))
            directionRequest.setDestination(MKMapItem(placemark: destPlacemark))
            directionRequest.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.Automobile


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in


                let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)

                directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler({ (
                    response, error) -> Void in

                    if (error != nil) {
                        NSLog("Error %@", error.description);

                    } else {
                        println("Route: \(response.routes.first)")
                        routeDetails = response.routes.first as! MKRoute



                        reply(["Distance" : routeDetails.distance, "TravelTime" : routeDetails.expectedTravelTime ]);
                    }
                })
            })
            })
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how we implemented `beginBackgroundTaskWithName`

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply{


Model *model=[Model sharedModel];

UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask __block = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"watchAppRequest" expirationHandler:^{

    NSLog(@"Background handler called. Background tasks expirationHandler called.");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

}];

//create an empty reply dictionary to be used later
NSDictionary *replyInfo __block=[NSDictionary dictionary];

//get the dictionary of info sent from watch
NSString *requestString=[userInfo objectForKey:@"request"];

//get the WatchAppHelper class (custom class with misc. functions)
WatchAppHelper *watchAppHelper=[WatchAppHelper sharedInstance];


//make sure user is logged in
if (![watchAppHelper isUserLoggedIn]) {

    //more code here to get user location and misc. inf.

    //send reply back to watch
    reply(replyInfo);

}


[app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
bgTask=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
```

}

Comment: not sure why this was voted down, it was in response to OP's follow up comment requesting for an example...

Comment: I finally took some time to check my own code, and it resembles what you're doing here, but it doesn't help. My watch app is still stuck on directions request if the iPhone app is asleep. As soon as I wake up the iPhone app, the watch app gets its directions response...

Comment: @Romain I posted a new answer with code that I can verify is working in our app. This also confirms that you can run `MKDirectionRequest` in the background. Maybe this can help shed some light...